# Perl problem with substituting UTF-8 string on windows

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, utf-8

I am trying to substitute substrings in a text file with Perl on Windows 10 using command line.

```
C:\Windows\System32\chcp 65001 & type test.txt | c:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl -CSD -pe "use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)'; binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8'); binmode(STDIN, ':encoding(utf8)'); s/__compare_loan__/So sánh sản phẩm cho vay/g"
```

**File test.txt (saved as UTF-8):**

Our benefit: `__compare_loan__`

**Output:**

> Active code page: 65001
> Our benefit: So sánh s?n ph?m cho vay

If I add `use utf8;` at the beginning of the Perl script, I get:

> Active code page: 65001 Malformed UTF-8 character: \xe1\x6e\x68
> (unexpected non-continuation byte 0x6e, immediately after start byte
> 0xe1; need 3 bytes, got 1) at -e line 1. Malformed UTF-8 character
> (fatal) at -e line 1.

Please any idea how do I get rid of the question marks in the output?

Comment: Works for me without issue with `use utf8;` with Win 11 `cmd` shell. Does it help if you use chcp 65001 first as a separate command? Are you typing/pasting the command, or is it saved in a .cmd file or .bat file? Are you using the cmd shell or PowerShell?

Comment: I used Win 10 both cmd and PowerShell with the same result. I copy pasted the command. Using chcp separately didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

That error when you add `use utf8;` to your one liner suggests that the arguments to perl are being given in CP-1252 or a similar code page, not in UTF-8 (0xE1 in CP-1252 is á, 0x6E is n and 0x68 is h).

One portable fix is to use character escapes instead of trying to include the non-ascii characters directly:

```bash
C:\Code\SO> chcp 65001 & type test.txt | perl -CSD -pe "s/__compare_loan__/So s\x{e1}nh s\x{1ea3}n ph\x{1ea9}m cho vay/g"
Active code page: 65001
Our benefit: So sánh sản phẩm cho vay
```

(Tested with Strawberry Perl 5.32.1 and the standard Windows 10 Command Prompt application)

Note that using `-CSD` means you don't need all that `use open` and `binmode` stuff; it's all implied by the arguments to `-C`.

Comment: Thank you. I think that it's not practical for me to escape the characters as I am creating the shell commands by formula in Google sheets line by line separately for many strings (for localization of source code). Is there any way to control in which encoding I am passing the arguments on the command line?